# Differential Equation $y(x)'=(y(x)+x)/(y(x)-x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

can someone give me some tips on how to solve this differential equation.
I looked at the Wolfram solution which substituted $y(x)=xv(x)$. I'd know how to solve from there, but I have know idea why they did it in the first place, well why the algorithm did it in the first place. When do you substitue $y(x)=xv(x)$?

What are other ways on solving it?

Comment: The reason that works is because the equation is *homogeneous* in the sense that the right hand side of the equality does not change if you multiply $x$ and $y$ by a constant. very time an equation has an invariance property like this, there is a way to simplify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**

$$y = v x \rightarrow y' = v + x v'$$

Substitute into original ODE. Looks like you know how to do this.

Why does this work?

To solve the equation $\tag 1 \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{f_1(x, y)}{f_2(x,y)},$

where $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ are homogeneous functions of the same degree in $x$ and $y$, we use the following approach. Let

$$f_1(x,y) = x^n \phi_1\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right), ~f_2(x,y) = x^n \phi_2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right).$$

From $(1)$, we have

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{f_1(x, y)}{f_2(x,y)} = \dfrac{x^n \phi_1\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)}{x^n \phi_2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)} = \dfrac{\phi_1\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)}{\phi_2\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)}$$

We can now write this as

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = f\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)$$

Now, if we say $v = \dfrac{y}{x} \rightarrow y = vx$ and we substitute, we get a separable equation of the form:

$$\dfrac{dv}{f(v) - v} = \dfrac{dx}{x}.$$

**Approach 2**

Let $x + y = z$.

We have $x + y = z \rightarrow 1 + \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dz}{dx} \rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dz}{dx} - 1$.

For the numerator, we substitute $z$ and for the denominator, we substitute $y-x = z-2x$. Do you see how to get that last one?

Now, the ODE is separable.

**Approach 3**

Let $y-x = z$.

Follow what was done in approach 2.

Comment: *What are other ways on solving it?*

Comment: @Amzoti
but why?
Like is there a guideline on when this substituion might work?

Comment: @Prankster: Added details as to why it works. Regards

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Added a second method and details as to why substitution works.

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks heaps. But for Approach 2, don't you mean y-x=z?
That way I get the correct solution. Haven't found a way to solve it using x+y=z

Comment: Needs a thumb's up! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks, just added more details and even a third approach. Hope you have a great day!

Comment: Nice "overtime" here! +2 if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a equation scaling $x \to \alpha x$ and $y \to \beta y$. Under such scaling the equation becomes
$$
y'
=
{\alpha \over \beta}\,
{y + \left(\alpha/\beta\right)x \over y - \left(\alpha/\beta\right)x}
$$
Then, we can see the equation doesn't change its form whenever $\alpha = \beta$. It means $y/x$ doesn't change its form either. Then, a change of variables
$\left(~y \to {\rm f}~\right)$ like $y/x = {\rm f}\left(x\right)$ should simplify the original equation as other people ( see @Amzoti ) already showed.

For this simple equation, this analysis can be too pretentious. However, it illustrates a general technique that can be quite useful in more complicated cases.

See, for example,
[Applications of Lie Groups to Difference Equations ( Differential and Integral Equations and Their Applications )](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420083090) 
by Vladimir Dorodnitsyn.